# htaccess directing wrong

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have following code,

**details.php** working fine. but when i access **gotolink.php** its directing me again in **details.php** page which giving me 404 error, cuz its unexpected url..

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ uk/details.php?pid=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ uk/details.php?pid=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ gotolink/gotolink.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ gotolink/gotolink.php?id=$1
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression for `details.php` and `gotolink.php` are identical, apache has no way to tell whether `http://domain.com/abc123` should be rewritten to `/uk/details.php?pid=abc123` or `/gotolink/gotolink.php?id=abc123` because the URI, `/abc123`, matches both of these:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ uk/details.php?pid=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ gotolink/gotolink.php?id=$1
```

The fact that the details.php one is first is why **everything** gets rewritten to details.php. If you swapped them around, everything would get rewritten to gotolink.php. You have to make it so these regular expressions match differently. Example:

```
RewriteRule ^d/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ uk/details.php?pid=$1

RewriteRule ^g/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ gotolink/gotolink.php?id=$1
```

So now `/d/abc123` goes to `/uk/details.php?pid=abc123` and `/g/abc123` goes to `/gotolink/gotolink.php?id=abc123`. Or you can separate them if the details pid is always letters and gotolink id is always numbers or something:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-/]+)$ uk/details.php?pid=$1

RewriteRule ^([0-9-/]+)$ gotolink/gotolink.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 2):

the rewrite conditions are the same so the first will catch all requests and it never gets to gotolink.php

Comment: what do you want to do at all?